# Постгрес: оптимизация запроса

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit

```
/*------ 04.02.2015 8:40:12 --------*/

EXPLAIN ANALYZE   SELECT  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM   "F_Date"),
            "F_ConvertedValue",
            "F_TagName_ID" FROM
            "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
            where
            "F_Date" > (localtimestamp - interval'1 hour') and
            "F_TagName_ID" in (73,72,39,64,76,75) 

            ORDER BY "F_Date" asc;;

/* Результат : "LOG:  duration: 11276.442 ms  statement: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "F_Date"), "F_ConvertedValue", "F_TagName_ID" FROM "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" where "F_Date" > (localtimestamp - interval'1 hour') and "F_TagName_ID" in (73,72,39,64,76,75) ORDER BY "F_Date" asc;;
```

Возвращено записей: 7 (выполнено: 11,279 с; всего: 11,279 с)" */

```
/*------ 04.02.2015 8:49:52 --------*/

EXPLAIN ANALYZE   SELECT  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM   "F_Date"),
            "F_ConvertedValue",
            "F_TagName_ID" FROM
            "SC_Tag"."T_TagData"
            where
            "F_Date" > (localtimestamp - interval'1 hour') and
            "F_TagName_ID" in (73,72,39,64,76,75) 

            --ORDER BY "F_Date" asc;;

/* Результат : "LOG:  duration: 9359.324 ms  statement: EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM "F_Date"), "F_ConvertedValue", "F_TagName_ID" FROM "SC_Tag"."T_TagData" where "F_Date" > (localtimestamp - interval'1 hour') and "F_TagName_ID" in (73,72,39,64,76,75)
```

Возвращено записей: 4 (выполнено: 9,360 с; всего: 9,375 с)" */

[image]

[image]

Это вообще кошмарно. Может, имеет смысл сортировать уже на клиенте али, может, какие другие соображения будут?

Comment: У вас есть индексы по полям `F_Date` и `F_TagName_ID`? Кажется, что Seq Scan по таблице в несколько десятков миллионов - не самая хорошая идея.

Answer (score 1):

CREATE INDEX